# gltf 2.0 model loads with failed depth testing in Vulkan

Tags: 3d, game-engine, vulkan, gltf

I am loading a sample gltf 2.0 model into my Vulkan program using a custom parser, everything loads fine except that on this particular 3d model (which is a bath duck model found on gltf 2.0 github page), the beak of the duck seems to be failing the depth testing.

the duck should look like this

[image]

However in my program it looks like this
[image]

here is the duck from another angle
[image]

Note that i have not applied the projection matrix yet, and i am inverting the y component of the model matrix as well as setting my front face to counter clockwise

Vulkan pipeline initialization

```
  void phantom::createGraphicsPipeline()
  {
auto vertShaderCode = readFile("shaders/vert.spv");
auto fragShaderCode = readFile("shaders/frag.spv");

createShaderModule(vertShaderCode, vertShaderModule);
createShaderModule(fragShaderCode, fragShaderModule);

VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo vertShaderStageInfo = {};
vertShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
vertShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
vertShaderStageInfo.module = vertShaderModule;
vertShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";

VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo fragShaderStageInfo = {};
fragShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
fragShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
fragShaderStageInfo.module = fragShaderModule;
fragShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";

VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shaderStages[] = { vertShaderStageInfo, fragShaderStageInfo };

//auto bindingDescription = getBindingDescription();
//auto attributeDescription = getAttributeDescription();

VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputInfo = {};
vertexInputInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
vertexInputInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = static_cast<uint32_t> (vertexBinding.size());
vertexInputInfo.pVertexBindingDescriptions = vertexBinding.data();
vertexInputInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(vertexAttributes.size());
vertexInputInfo.pVertexAttributeDescriptions = vertexAttributes.data();

VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly = {};
inputAssembly.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
inputAssembly.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
inputAssembly.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;

VkViewport viewport = {};
viewport.x = 0.0f;
viewport.y = 0.0f;
viewport.width = (float)swapChainExtend.width;
viewport.height = (float)swapChainExtend.height;
viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;

VkRect2D scissor = {};
scissor.offset = { 0,0 };
scissor.extent = swapChainExtend;

VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState = {};
viewportState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
viewportState.pViewports = &viewport;
viewportState.scissorCount = 1;
viewportState.pScissors = &scissor;

VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer = {};
rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
rasterizer.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
rasterizer.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
rasterizer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE;
rasterizer.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;
rasterizer.depthBiasConstantFactor = 0.0f;
rasterizer.depthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
rasterizer.depthBiasSlopeFactor = 0.0f;

VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampling = {};
multisampling.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
multisampling.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;
multisampling.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
multisampling.minSampleShading = 1.0f;
multisampling.pSampleMask = nullptr;
multisampling.alphaToCoverageEnable = VK_FALSE;
multisampling.alphaToOneEnable = VK_FALSE;

VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo depthStencil = {};
depthStencil.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DEPTH_STENCIL_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
depthStencil.depthTestEnable = VK_TRUE;
depthStencil.depthWriteEnable = VK_TRUE;
depthStencil.depthCompareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS;
depthStencil.depthBoundsTestEnable = VK_FALSE;
depthStencil.minDepthBounds = 0.0f;
depthStencil.maxDepthBounds = 1.0f;
depthStencil.stencilTestEnable = VK_FALSE;
depthStencil.front = {};
depthStencil.back = {};

VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment = {};
colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;
colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_FALSE;
colorBlendAttachment.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
colorBlendAttachment.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
colorBlendAttachment.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
colorBlendAttachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
colorBlendAttachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
colorBlendAttachment.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;

VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending = {};
colorBlending.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
colorBlending.logicOpEnable = VK_FALSE;
colorBlending.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY;
colorBlending.attachmentCount = 1;
colorBlending.pAttachments = &colorBlendAttachment;
colorBlending.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f;
colorBlending.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f;
colorBlending.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f;
colorBlending.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f;

VkDynamicState dynamicStates[] = {
    VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT,
    VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_LINE_WIDTH
};

VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamicState = {};
dynamicState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DYNAMIC_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
dynamicState.dynamicStateCount = 2;
dynamicState.pDynamicStates = dynamicStates;

VkDescriptorSetLayout setLayouts[] = { descriptorSetLayout };

VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutInfo = {};
pipelineLayoutInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
pipelineLayoutInfo.setLayoutCount = 1;
pipelineLayoutInfo.pSetLayouts = setLayouts;
pipelineLayoutInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;
pipelineLayoutInfo.pPushConstantRanges = 0;

if (vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &pipelineLayoutInfo, nullptr, &pipelineLayout) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to create pipeline layout !");
}

VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo = {};
pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
pipelineInfo.stageCount = 2;
pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages;
pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputInfo;
pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
pipelineInfo.pDepthStencilState = &depthStencil;
pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlending;
pipelineInfo.pDynamicState = nullptr;
pipelineInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
pipelineInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
pipelineInfo.subpass = 0;
pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
pipelineInfo.basePipelineIndex = -1;

if (vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineInfo, nullptr, &graphicsPipeline) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to create graphics pipeline! ");
}
}
```

transformation matrix fed to the command buffer

```
glm::mat4 rotationMat = glm::rotate(10.f,glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::mat4 translateMat = glm::translate(glm::vec3(0, 0, 0));
glm::mat4 scaleMat = glm::scale(glm::vec3(30, 30, 30));
glm::mat4 modelMat = v.model.transformation[0] * scaleMat * rotationMat;
//v.model.transformation[0] = rotationMat * v.model.transformation[0];
modelMat[1][1] = modelMat[1][1] * -1;
v.updateUniformBuffer(modelMat);
```

depth resource and renderpass creation debug messages
[image]

Render pass creation method

```
void phantom::createRenderPass()
{
std::cout << "entered renderpass creation" << std::endl;

VkAttachmentDescription colorAttachment = {};
colorAttachment.format = swapChainImageFormat;
colorAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
colorAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
colorAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
colorAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
colorAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

VkAttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef = {};
colorAttachmentRef.attachment = 0;
colorAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentDescription depthAttachment = {};
depthAttachment.format = findDepthFormat();
depthAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
depthAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
depthAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
depthAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
depthAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
depthAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
depthAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference depthAttachmentRef = {};
depthAttachmentRef.attachment = 1;
depthAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;


VkSubpassDescription subPass = {};
subPass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subPass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subPass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;
subPass.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthAttachmentRef;

std::vector <VkAttachmentDescription> attachments = { colorAttachment, depthAttachment };

VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo = {};
renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = attachments.size();
renderPassInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subPass;

VkSubpassDependency dependency = {};
dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
dependency.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;

renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
renderPassInfo.pDependencies = &dependency;

if (vkCreateRenderPass(device, &renderPassInfo, nullptr, &renderPass) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to create render pass ! ");
}


}
```

FrameBuffer Creation method

```
void phantom::createFrameBuffer()
{
swapChainFramebuffers.resize(swapChainImageViews.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < swapChainImageViews.size(); i++)
{
    std::vector<VkImageView> attachments = { swapChainImageViews[i], depthImageView };

    VkFramebufferCreateInfo framebufferInfo = {};
    framebufferInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    framebufferInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
    framebufferInfo.attachmentCount = attachments.size();
    framebufferInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
    framebufferInfo.width = swapChainExtend.width;
    framebufferInfo.height = swapChainExtend.height;
    framebufferInfo.layers = 1;

    if (vkCreateFramebuffer(device, &framebufferInfo, nullptr, &swapChainFramebuffers[i]) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create framebuffer!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: To me this does look like a depth test problem, paired with a skewed aspect ratio.  What happens if you flip `depthStencil.depthCompareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS;` to be greater instead of less?

Comment: @emackey when i set it to be greater it does not show anything at all, and whatever the setting configuration i tried it always has that problem, is there any other possibility that it might be caused by any other field other than depth testing?

Comment: I see you invert y in ur glm matrix, did u also adjust z from -1/1 to 0/1.

Comment: @yngccc yes i forced glm to re adjust z as 0 - 1 using `#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE` at the top of my header file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gltf was designed with OpenGl in mind, thus it accepts (depth Values) of (-1 to 1), so whenever you want to use gltf with Vulkan you have to compensate for that since Vulkan expects depth range of (0 to 1).

in my example i was sending the vertex data to the shader in raw binary format, so technically i was not mapping the z value to the range required by Vulkan, i applied the required range mapping to the depth value and the problem is resolved.

here is the result of my program
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other bits of the mesh seem to be missing too (tail maybe? or is that just occluded?). My guess would be face culling rather than depth testing. Try `rasterizer.cullMode == VK_CULL_MODE_NONE`?

Comment: the cull mode made things even worse, the tail is not missing its just that i have not fed the perspective projection matrix and my model is flattened by the applied transformation, i edited the question with a new view angle of the duck picture as well as the transformation matrix operations.

Comment: Silly question - do You have depth attachment added to both a render pass and a framebuffer? Or maybe depth values are inverted - what is further away is treated as if it nearer the camera and vice versa. Try inverting depth setup in a viewport.

Comment: @Ekzuzy i tried to reverse the depth comparison operation, inverted the Z value, i even tried to use an identity matrix just to make sure it was not inverting coordinate values still the problem is not getting resolved, i updated the post with the debug messages regarding depth and renderpass stages.

Comment: @BulBul Maybe show us render pass and framebuffer creation code. Debug messages doesn't show anything useful. There is a pipeline barrier problem but (unless it has something to do with layout transitions) it shouldn't have such impact.

Comment: @Ekzuzy i updated the question with the framebuffer and renderpass creation code.

Comment: This looks fine. Could You share Your project somewhere (I hope it's for Windows)? I can debug it as I don't see anything wrong in the code parts You showed in the question.

Comment: @Ekzuzy you can find the project files as well as the dependent libraries  [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tqAaJAuTUYzVCTJ-SXVEGFsnMvaZ-kAi), kindly ignore the strange naming and messy code  as this was intended to experiment on the vulkan gltf integration, I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ekzuzy i think i found a possible cause of this issue, I am sending the vertex attributes to the shader using raw binary data by which `#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE`  has no effect on it, i tried to map the vertex range -1 -> 1 to 0 -> 1 in the vertex shader something definitely improved but the problem was still there, is there any function to map a binary array to a vector of vec3? so that glm would automatically map the z value to the correct range.

Comment: @BulBul It's great that You solved Your problem!! I'm sorry I didn't look into Your project. I had a very tough week and I, unfortunately, I didn't have time. :-(

Comment: @Ekzuzy there is nothing to be sorry about, i highly appreciate the time you took to help me on this issue, it was a great challenge for me to learn more about the behavior of vulkan and gltf so it is a double win :)